# Как заполнить массив элементами на которые я кликаю и вывести их на экран через запятую?

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, typescript, react-hook

У меня есть компонент Popup-menu меню в котором я отфильтровываю свою базу данных фруктов из компонента App и вывожу их на экран. Я хочу при клике на эти выведенные фрукты размещать их в компоненте App в div.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я передаю фрукт на который кликнул в компонент App в функцию selectItems и помещаю её в массив, чтобы я потом смог вывести несколько фруктов, на которые я кликнул, на экран.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данный момент при клике на какой-нибудь фрукт я помещаю в массив только его. После того как кликаю на другой фрукт, он становиться вместо первого. Как мне помещать в массив несколько фруктов на которые я кликаю, чтобы вывести из всех потом на экран через запятую?
Вот так выглядит поп ап я элементы которого я кликаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так происходит потому что вы не обновляете массив, а добавляете новый. Вам надо создать новый массив и добавить его. Сделать это можно вот так : `setSelectedItems([...selectedItems, item])`

Comment: Блин не понял. Мне нужно создать новое состояние-пустой массив? И после моего setSelected(selectedItems) добавить setSelectedItems([...selectedItems, item]) ? Что-то не получается

Comment: Нет, там где сетаешь данные сделай setSelectedItems([...selectedItems, тут то что хочешь добавить в массив])